# Get an object in collection by object index

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of objects

`[{name: Peter}, {name: Evan}, {name: Michael}];`

I and i want to get an object for example {name: Evan} by his index(1).

How can i pull this out?

I tried get All objects by find() and then get an object with index but it's not a good idea in terms of speed.

Comment: Does that array represent three different documents in the collection or is that an array within a single document? What do you mean by "by the index"? How do you know Evan is in the second position?

Comment: yes they are different documents. By the index I mean const users = await User.find(); users[1] // {name: "Evan"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few notable aspects of this question. In the comments you clarify:

> yes they are different documents. By the index I mean const users = await User.find(); users[1] // {name: "Evan"}

Probably what you are looking to do here is something along the lines of:

```
const users = await User.find().skip(1).limit(1);
```

This will return a cursor that will contain just the single document that you are looking for.

Keep in mind, however, that the without providing a `sort` to the operation the database is free to return the results in any order. So the "index" (position) is not guaranteed to be consistent without the sort clause.

> I tried get All objects by find() and then get an object with index but it's not a good idea in terms of speed.

In general, your current approach requires that the database iterate through all of the items being skipped which [can be slow](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#using-skip--). Limiting the results at least reduces the amount of network activity that is required. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could consider setting a smaller batch size (and iterating the cursor) or using range queries as outlined on that page.

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped! Please consider marking this as the accepted answer to indicate to others that the question has been addressed